# RegEx to match <a> html tags without specific attribute

Tags: java, regex

In Java I need to match `<a>` tags in a string that do not have href attribute. For example in the following string:

```
text <a class="aClass" href="#">link1</a> text <a class="aClass" target="_blank">link2</a> text
```

it should not match `<a class="aClass" href="#">link1</a>` (because it contains href) but it should match `<a class="aClass" target="_blank">link2</a>` (because it does not contain href).

I managed to build the RegEx to match my  tags:

```
<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>
```

but I can not figure out how to eliminate  tags with href

(I know I can use HTML parsers etc but I need to do this with RegEx.

Comment: Why do you need to use regex? [HTML is not a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: There are a variety of reasons why parsing HTML with a regular expression is preferred. Some editors will allow the use of a regex expression for search and replacing where as the same editor doesn't support "insert your html parsing code here". Or attempting to pull data out of very badly formatted html code can throw parsing errors.  Or the homework assignment said to use regex and not a parsing engine. Or what if the document wasn't even html instead contained html examples... Agree or disagree, parsing html with an engine isn't always the best available solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure people are running bot-like scripts that, whenever there is a question with both the "html" and "regex" words, they automatically post a link to that *"You can't parse [X]HTML with regex..."* answer. Hilarious.

Comment: LOL they probably use a parsing engine for that too.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Description

Be careful with regexs like `<a[^>]*` as these will also match other valid html tags which start with an `a` such as `<abbr>` or `<address>`. Also simply looking for the existence of the string `href` isn't good enough as that string could be inside the value of another attribute or such as `<a class="thishrefstuff"...`, or part of another attribute like `<a hreflang="en"...`

This expression will:

- match all anchor tags `<a`...`</a>` which don't contain a `href` attribute.
- It will enforce the tag name is `a` and not a tag which simply starts with the letter `a` like `<address>`
- ignore attributes which also have the substring `href` embedded in the name of the attribute like the valid `hreflang='en'` or the made up `Attributehref="some value"`.
- ignore all characters inside the value portion of all properly formatted attributes like `bogus='href=""'`

`<a(?=\s|>)(?!(?:[^>=]|=(['"])(?:(?!\1).)*\1)*?\shref=['"])[^>]*>.*?<\/a>`

[image]

## Expanded

- `<a(?=\s|>)` match the open tag and ensure the next after the tag name is either a space or the close bracket, this forces the name to be `a` and not something else
- `(?!` start the negative look ahead this if we find an href in this tag then this type of tag isn't the tag we're looking for

  - `(?:` start non capture group to move through all characters inside the tag
  - `[^>=]` match all non tag closing characters which prevents the regex engine from leaving the tag, and non equal signs which prevents the engine from continuing blindly matching all characters
  - `|` or
  - `=(['"])` match an equal sign followed by an open double or single quote. the quote is captured into group 2 so it can be correctly paired later
  - `(?:(?!\1).)*` match all characters which are not the a close quote that matches the open quote
  - `\1` match the correct close quote
  - `)*?` close the non capture group and repeat is as often as necessary until
  - `\shref=['"]` matching the desired href attribute. The `\s` and `=["']` ensures the attribute name is simply href
  - `)` close the negative lookahead
- `[^>]*>.*?<\/a>` match the entire string from open to close

## Java Code Example:

**Input text**

`<abbr>RADIO</abbr> text <a class="aClass" href="#">link1</a> text <a bogus='href=""' class="aClass" target="_blank">link2</a> text`

**Code**

If you're looking to use this in a replace function to remove non-href-anchor tags then just replace all matches with nothing.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("<a(?=\\s|>)(?!(?:[^>=]|=(['\"])(?:(?!\\1).)*\\1)*?\\shref=['\"])[^>]*>.*?<\\/a>
",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Matches**

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <a bogus='href=""' class="aClass" target="_blank">link2</a>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: Perfect answer. It works great with what I am trying to do. The only issue (for someone else) might be that in case there is an href attribute without quote, it will match it. For example: `<a href=http://www.java.com></a>`

Answer (score 9):

I find it odd that you would *need* to do it with regex, but you can use a negative lookahead.

```
<a(?![^>]+href).*?>(.*?)</a>
```

Comment: @Raedwald it could with DOTALL

Answer (score 0):

I am not a java expert, but you can try something like this:

```
String regex = new String("(?i)<a(?>[^h>]++|(?<! )h++|h++(?!ref\\s*+=))*>((?>[^<]++|<(?!/a>))*)</a>");
String replacement = new String("$1");
str.replaceAll(regex,replacement);
```

Answer (score -1):

One option you have is to first match *all*  tags and then use a regex to match the ones that have  so that you can ignore them. So your pseudo code would look like:

```
<a>tags = html.find(all<a>tags);
for(String <a>tag : <a>tags){
    if(<a>tag.isHref()) continue;
    //do proccessing
}
```

Comment: -1 The OP specified how to do this with regex and not an html parsing engine.

Comment: @Denomales Its pseudo code... not an html parsing engine. I dont link or say its a parser anywhere, Im just suggesting an alternative usage of the regex.